# Change tracking - sys_change_operation are all "I"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, change-tracking

I created a test table.

```
create table test (Id int not null, ......) 
  ON [PRIMARY] WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
GO
ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id) 
  WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_timestamp] ON test ([timestamp]) 
  WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE test ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

**update: the table has a trigger writing the PKs of all the changes in another table**

And I inserted some values in the table. Then updated one row using `update test set ... where Id = 1`.

However the following query returns all "I" for sys_change_operation? What can cause the problem? (BTW, I tried to enable CDC, however it doesn't capture anything.)

```
select distinct commit_time,sys_change_operation, count(*)
-- select *
from
    changetable(changes dbo.test, 0) c
    join sys.dm_tran_commit_table tc on c.sys_change_version = tc.commit_ts
group by commit_time, sys_change_operation
```

Results:

```
commit_time             sys_change_operation Count
----------------------- -------------------- -----------
2014-05-29 22:39:22.397 I                    5944
2014-05-29 22:47:41.220 I                    1 
(The last row should be "U")
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this excellent article [here](https://simonlearningsqlserver.wordpress.com/tag/changetable/). It explains why you are seeing this behavior. The issue is to do with 0 being passed as argument to CHANGETABLE.